# how to work with SVN properties(bugtraq:logregex)

Tags: svn, jira, subclipse, svn-propset

I found a Eclipse plugin requiring the bugtraq:logregex of SVN properties.  The bugtraq:logregex property suppose to be my Jira ticket ID. I am wondering how will this function works. Is that like this:

1. Find the Jira ticket ID
2. Add SVN properties bugtrap:logregex=JiraID by `svn propset svn:bugtraq:logregex`
3. SVN Commit

However, I think my step 2 is setting properties to a file, I still do not know how to set SVN properties to the project.
Besides, we are not using Tortoisesvn, and we use Subclipse in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Modify your code
2. `svn add [files]` in your command line
3. Go to jira find your Jira ticket ID, for example "TASK-273"
4. `svn propset bugtraq:logrex "TASK-273"` ./ (svn help propset for more info)
5. `svn commit -m "your commit message"`
6. Check if the SVN property has been successfully set by `svn propget bugtraq:logrex`